# Generating numbers from normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I'm trying to test the speed of generating numbers from normal distribution by using Box–Muller transform against Marsaglia polar method. It is said that Marsaglia polar method is suppose to be faster than Box–Muller transform because it does not need to compute sin and cos. However, when I code this in Python, this is not true. Can someone verify this or explain to me why this is happening?

```
def marsaglia_polar():
    while True:
        x = (random.random() * 2) - 1
        y = (random.random() * 2) - 1
        s = x * x + y * y
        if s < 1:
            t = math.sqrt((-2) * math.log(s)/s)
            return x * t, y * t

def box_muller():
    u1 = random.random()
    u2 = random.random()

    t = math.sqrt((-2) * math.log(u1))
    v = 2 * math.pi * u2

    return t * math.cos(v), t * math.sin(v)
```

Comment: Without seeing your code!?

Comment: We can, if you show us your code

Comment: So I'm seeing box_muller win by 10 to 20% as well; possibly the rejection sampling is enough of a slowdown to overshadow the trig functions. That being said, if you care enough about doing this fast that that kind of difference matters to you, you shouldn't be doing it in pure Python in the first place.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I'm generating a million random numbers with either method in under a second. But yes, `box_muller` is winning by 10-15%. It seems that about 25% of the `marsaglia_polar` runs generate at least one `s >= 1` and that seems to be enough to lose out.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point. If an extra 0.2s per million calls actually matters to you, you probably want to do it in another lang. And yes, considering it's sampling a circle inscribed in a square, only `pi/4` candidates will actually pass the first time.

Comment: This is my homework problem. It asks me to implement the two and state their run time. However, I don't want to lose marks as marsaglia_polar is suppose to be faster than box_muller.

Comment: You should present your results as you got them. I doubt you'll lose points because of what's *supposed to be* faster -- if you do I'm incredibly disappointed with your prof. The whole point of measuring things is to find out what *actually is*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "fun", I wrote it up in go. The `box_muller` function is faster there as well. Also, it's about 10 times faster than the python version.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    now := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        marsaglia_polar()
    }
    fmt.Println("marsaglia_polar duration = ", time.Since(now))
    now = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        box_muller()
    }
    fmt.Println("box_muller duration      = ", time.Since(now))
}

func marsaglia_polar() (float64, float64) {
    for {
        x := random() * 2 - 1;
        y := random() * 2 - 1;
        s := x * x + y * y;
        if s < 1 {
            t := math.Sqrt((-2) * math.Log(s)/s);
            return x * t, y * t
        }
    }
}

func box_muller() (float64, float64) {
    u1 := random()
    u2 := random()
    t := math.Sqrt((-2) * math.Log(u1))
    v := 2 * math.Pi * u2
    return t * math.Cos(v), t * math.Sin(v)
}

func random() float64 {
    return rand.Float64()
}
```

Output:

```
marsaglia_polar duration =  104.308126ms
box_muller duration      =  88.365933ms
```